# CSS - Change Element tag and replace its content

Tags: css

I don't have access to the HTML page so I'm stuck using CSS Content to replace text. The text I'm replacing uses h1 title tags and I'm trying to replace said text with using h3 tags.

```
.class::before {
content: '<h3> Replacement Text </h3>';
```

On at least Chrome and IE the title tags are ignored. The replacement text does display but in default h1 title tag.

Comment: You can't add an HTML element, nor replace existing elements, to your page using solely CSS. **(1)** Psuedo-elements don't replace the content, they add an additional section of content *before* or *after* the existing content.  **(2)** You can't add HTML elements using psuedo-elements or the `content` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. You just saved me several hours of pain.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want an `<h3>` instead of an `<h1>`? If it's solely for display purposes, or just to change the text, there are workarounds. If you specifically need an `<h3>` though, you'll need to go a different route (JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option for this situation is to style the class as an h3, overriding the h1 styling. As long as the styling for this class is below the styling for h1, it should take precedence.

You'll also need to hide the original content because `content` doesn't replace content.

For example:

```css
h3 {
        font-size:2em;
        color:#424242;
    }
    .class {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .class::after {
        content: 'Replacement Text';
        visibility: visible;
        font-size:2em;
        color:#424242;
    }
```

```html
<h3 class="class">text</h3>
```

Comment: If this answer answered your question, could you accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't change the tag itself.

But you can change its content with css trick:

**See This Demo**

```css
h1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  content: 'Applied From CSS';
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

</style>
```

```html
<h1>Applied From HTML</h1>
```